# "LookupError: Function `__class__` does not exist." When using tf.function

Tags: python, oop, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to override a keras/tf2.0 loss function with a custom one abstracted in a WebAssembly binary. Here is the relevant code.

```py
@tf.function
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.constant(instance.exports.loss(y_true, y_pred))
```

and I am using it this way

```py
model.compile(optimizer_obj, loss=custom_loss)
# and then model.fit(...)
```

I am not entirely sure how the tf2.0 eager execution works, so any insights regarding that would be useful.

I don't think the instance.exports.loss function is relevant to the error, however if you are sure everything else is alright, let me know and I will share additional details.

Here is a stacktrace and the actual error:
https://pastebin.com/6YtH75ay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need not use `@tf.function` in order to define a custom loss.

We can happily (if pointlessly) do something like this:

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return tf.reduce_mean(y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=custom_loss,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

so long as all the operations we use inside `custom_loss` **are differentiable by tensorflow**

So you can remove the `@tf.function` decorator but then I suspect you will then run into an error message something like this:

```
[Some trace info] - Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

because there is no way for tensorflow to be able to find the gradients of a function in a webassembly binary. Everything inside that loss function must be something tensorflow can understand and compute gradients on otherwise it will not be able to optimise for a lower loss value.

Perhaps the best way forward would be to replicate the functionality inside `instance.exports.loss` using operations that tensorflow can compute gradients on rather than trying to reference it directly?

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks. 
How do you define operations that tensorflow can compute gradients on? What is the requirement for that? Does it need to be necessarily in python, or could I use C++ tensorflow for the operations and then use them in python?

Comment: @ViktorVelev My Pleasure :-) If it helped you feel free to upvote and/or accept! The requirement is that the mathematical function is differentiable and that tensorflow knows how to translate it to one of it's operations. I recognise that the latter clause in that sentence isn't super clear - I guess thats because of the wonderful work that the tf team have done on autograph to automatically translate a lot of python functinality to operations the tf graph can compute. You're certainly on safe ground when you use tf.[some_function] if some_function is a differentiable one.

Comment: I believe I read somewhere that writing your own custom operations in C++ is do-able but I have never attempted it so can't really advise. I'd guess you'd then have to know how to comupte the gradients yourself. What exactly does the binary loss function do? For almost all use-cases we can use exiting tf ops.

Comment: The goal is modularity and secrecy (the python training function should not have access to the source code of the loss function)